# Transform jQuery $.ajax into axios request to fetch HTML

Tags: jquery, ajax, axios

I am struggeling to translate a jQuery $.ajax request into an axios request.

This is the original ajax request, it returns a snippet of HTML just fine:

```
$.ajax(source, {
'method': 'GET',
'dataType': 'html',
'data': {
    'foo': 'bar'
  }
}
```

This is the axios request I've build so far which does not return the snippet of HTML but the whole website instead:

```
const options = {
  url: source,
  method: "GET",
  contentType: "text/html"
  params: {
    'foo': 'bar'
  },
};

axios(options).then((response) => {
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

What am I missing? I've compared the headers in the Google dev tools network tab and can't see a difference...

Comment: The two snippets of code would produce the same request. Check the requests in devtools to find any differences between them in your local environment. My guess would be that you've used something like `$.ajaxSetup()` elsewhere in your jQuery code to automatically define pre-set headers/auth tokens in all subsequent AJAX requests which has been missed from the Axios translation.

Comment: Also note that returning the entire HTML page is the standard behaviour. If something is filtering it on the server side, then this would appear to be an issue there. If it's being filtered client-side, then you need to also translate whatever jQuery logic is doing that in to Axios too.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thx for your response! There is no $.ajaxSetup anywhere and the $.ajax returns <li></li> inside the response already which is the desired result. The axios request however returns the whole page instead of the <li></li>.